# Excel extract text from alphanumeric in last filled cell in a row

Tags: excel

Hi this request may be very specific but I have a row of cells that are filled in alphanumeric such as

[image]

Lets say column 1 is A with the row names. I want column 2 to show the latest cell filled to the right (for row 2 it would be PL0.25)

I also want the number to be removed, so only PL is written. Is there a formula that can do all of that in one line?

Comment: Answer here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2104-excel-return-first-last-non-blank-cell-in-row-column.html

Comment: What about extracting the text part only?

Comment: Good question, I don't know how to do that, at least not from Excel (it can be done fairly easily with VBA).

Comment: Is the text constant length? It is always before the number? Can text be around a number? I.e. is there a pattern that can be used to determine the text part? What do typical and edge cases look like for  data? I am using the term text loosely here to mean [a-zA-Z]

Comment: I can say that the text is constant length, and will always end with 3 digits such as BL0.25, PL1.00, BF0.00

The text will also be uppercase for both letters.

Comment: ending with 3 digits and 1 dot?  Leading with how many character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you always want the Left two characters then as below. This could go in A1 and then you drag down rows.

```
=LEFT(LOOKUP(2,1/(1:1<>""),1:1),2)
```

To be sure of last with Text only and to handle strings less than two in length try:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(INDEX(1:1,,MATCH("zzz",1:1)),2),"")
```

Comment: This works too, and I am not forced to format the numbers to a particular decimal point as compared to the other answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

write  `=LEFT(INDEX(2:2,MAX(IF($D2:$ZZ2<>"",COLUMN($D2:$ZZ2),""))),LEN(INDEX(2:2,MAX(IF($D2:$ZZ2<>"",COLUMN($D2:$ZZ2),""))))-4)` in `B2`
then press `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: This works thank you, only thing I have to keep constant is the length of the entry, for example BL0.5 will not return the correct value meanwhile BL0.50 will.

Comment: @joon25 In my formula, the ending `-4` is to cut the final 4 characters.  So, in `BL0.50` case, `0.50` will be cut, and show `BL`.  In `BL0.5` case, `L0.5` will be cut, and show `B`.